# Basic Trigger - Create Record if Box is checked

Tags: apex, trigger

Have a very basic trigger below and it works fine...added custom checkbox to Account: Create_Contact__c. What is the IF() syntax to execute the trigger IF that box is checked?

```
trigger insertContact on Account (after insert)     
 {
 Contact cont = new Contact();
 cont.LastName = Trigger.new[0].name;
 cont.AccountId = Trigger.new[0].ID; 
 insert cont;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the boolean value of the checkbox as below. Hope this helps

```
trigger insertContact on Account (after insert) {
    for (Account account : Trigger.new) {
        if(account.Create_Contact__c == true){
            //Do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, looks so easy but I couldn't get it right!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you will likely want to make a few changes. First, your trigger will need to take in the 'After Update' event as well since checking a box on the account is an 'update' event.

```
trigger insertContact on Account (after insert, after update)
```

Next, your trigger is currently only set up to handle a single object. It is best practice to bulkify your trigger so that it can handle any number of records entering that trigger context. Something along these lines should work:

```
trigger insertContact on Account (after insert, after update){

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        for(Account acct : trigger.new){
            Account oldAcct = trigger.oldMap.get(acct.Id);
            if(acct.Create_Contact__c == true && oldAcct.Create_Contact__c == false){
                Contact cont = new Contact(
                    lastName = 'lastName',
                    firstName = 'firstName',
                    AccountId = acct.Id
                );
                contactList.add(cont);
            }
        }
        if(!contactList.isEmpty()){
            insert contactList;
        }
    }
```

So, in the example above, we start by evaluating the trigger context to only run our bit of code if it's After Update. This is important because we always want to assume that there are multiple Account records that could be entering this trigger any time it is called. If an Account is being inserted, for example, we would not want it to enter our code that should only apply for accounts that are being updated with that checkbox.

```
if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
```

Next, we instantiate a list of Contacts. This is key to bulkifying your trigger. By creating a list, we are able to store records that need to inserted or (in this case) updated and perform our insert/update operation on all at the same time - rather than one at a time, which will eat away at your limits and could cause failures for you down the road. We then loop through all Account records entering the trigger for that operation and, using the 'trigger.oldMap', retrieve the 'old Account' - the oldMap stores a version of the record prior to when any changes were made. For example, in the case of this checkbox, when the user selects that checkbox and clicks save, the Account in 'trigger.new' would show that checkBox == true, while the Account stored in the oldMap would show that the checkBox == false.

```
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        for(Account acct : trigger.new){
            Account oldAcct = trigger.oldMap.get(acct.Id);
```

Next, we add further logic to only create contacts IF that checkbox was checked. This compares the new Vs. the old to see that this box WAS previously unchecked, and NOW is checked. We then create out new Contact record and add it to the List we created above.

```
        if(acct.Create_Contact__c == true && oldAcct.Create_Contact__c == false){
            Contact cont = new Contact(
                lastName = 'lastName',
                firstName = 'firstName',
                AccountId = acct.Id
            );
            contactList.add(cont);
```

Finally, we check to see if our list of Contacts is empty. If it is empty, it means that no Accounts that entered this trigger had the Create_Contact__c checkbox checked and, thus, no need for further action. However, if the List does contain records, it means some Accounts did meet this criteria and we do want to insert those contacts we created for those given accounts. We do so with the last piece of code:

```
    if(!contactList.isEmpty()){
        insert contactList;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Chris this is VERY helpful, I've read through your info a few times and it is starting to make sense...I appreciate you taking the time to write this!

Comment: Realize now that I misunderstood that you were only wanting this operation to be performed on insert, but perhaps there are still a few takeaways from my post :)

Comment: Yes only on Account Create, but it's just an example I made up anyway to learn, and your info was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

This is what your trigger should look like:

Inside your trigger, you'd want to test the following:

```
trigger insertContact on Account (after insert){

set<account>toCtcs = new set<account();
For(account a:trigger.new){
   If(a.Create_Contact__c == true){
      toCtcs(add a);
   }

// Run a for loop on the set of accounts to create the contacts & add them to a list

list<contact>newCtcs = new list<contact>();

For(account c:toCtcs){

   // add your logic with the fields from accts
   Contact cont = new Contact();
   cont.LastName = c.name;
   cont.AccountId = c.ID;

   newCtcs.add(cont);

}

// Insert Contact records

 Insert newCtcs;


 // When you're finished inserting the contacts, you'll want to reset the value of 
 // Create_Contact__c to false before you end the trigger and update Accounts when you do.

list<account>toUpdate = new list<account>();

For(account ac:toCtcs){

   ac.Create_Contact__c == false;

   toUpdate.add(ac);
}

update toUpdate;

} // end of trigger
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am so new to apex I don't know how to do that. I am just trying to get an understanding of basic syntax now

Comment: see my edits with more details. If you're that new, you'll want to go through the [Trailhead Apex Trigger Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules).

Comment: you lost me...I'm trying to add "account.Create_Contact__c = false" to flip the checkbox back to unchecked but don't know where to add it, and I suspect it's not nearly as easy as that

Comment: as of now this is working: trigger insertContact on Account (after insert)
 {
    for (Account account : Trigger.new)
    {if(account.Create_Contact__c == true)
            {Contact cont = new Contact();
                cont.LastName = 'James';
                cont.AccountId = Trigger.new[0].ID; 
                insert cont;}}
 }

Comment: Started going through the Trailhead yesterday. Even their basic Apex tutorial wasn't making sense for me!

Comment: After you insert your contacts, that's when the section of code starts above where I have the `list<account>toUpdate`. You can't do it all as shown with the code in the other answer. You also need to add your new contacts to a list as in `list<contact>newCtcs`, then insert them after your for loop.

Comment: Would you mind adding the code block above with everything together? That i could copy and paste in the dev org to see if it works?

Comment: I get variable does not exist - trigger insertContact on Account (after insert)
 {
    for (Account account : Trigger.new)
    {if(account.Create_Contact__c == true)
            {Contact cont = new Contact();
                cont.LastName = 'James';
                cont.AccountId = Trigger.new[0].ID; 
                insert cont;}}
                
                list<account>toUpdate = new list<account>();
For(account ac:toCtcs){

   ac.Create_Contact__c == false;

   toUpdate.add(ac);
}

update toUpdate;
 }

Comment: You can't use `for(account : trigger.new)`. Its  `for(account a : trigger.new)`, then you use `a.Create_Contact__c`. You've copied the code incorrectly.

Comment: Complete code for you above. Please study and try to learn from it.